# SAP: Is there a cross platform HTML web based client?

Tags: html, user-interface, client, cross-platform, sap-gui

I'm aware of the client in the form of a Windows application (which uses SAP's own interface standards) but is there a HTML based client that one can freely download with the same functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to SAP GUI, there is a Java version.  I've used it under both Linux and Windows.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, is there somewhere you can download it and is the source open? Reason for asking about open source is I would like to automate some tasks manually fetching information from SAP.

Comment: I'll +1 and accept your answer if you can tell me where to find it and how to configure it. :)

Comment: It has been a while and I don't remember the address, but SAP has a portal where you can download everything you're licensed to use.  I remember it also coming on a resource CD and was fairly common.  You just had to drill down deep into the directories on the CD.  As for if it is open source, I doubt it.  To automate getting data from SAP, there are a number of better ways of doing it rather than going through the GUI.  Try looking at the Java connection (JCo) or .Net connector to call BAPIs.  There may even be a way to expose the BAPIs as web services.

Comment: +1 accepted answer with last comment. Thanks - that sets the scene. Shame that it's not open enough to provide APIs without licenses for what is, after all, a database with some logic and user access control privileges.

Comment: SAP doesn't give out anything for free. ;)

Answer (score 1):

All of the different SAP client platforms are detailed on SAP's SDN site: http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/sdn/sap-gui

You can see there is a GUI for Windows, and for Java (e.g. for Linux or Mac users).

There is also the SAP GUI for HTML (aka ITS webgui) which is probably what you are after. This allows access via a web browser, without needing to install a specific client application. It does require some setup on the SAP server however.

Comment: Can I just download any of this for free though??? rather than pay for it or persuade the powers-that-be to spend their limited budget on this?

Comment: ( PS +1 for the answer, the link looks very intriguing as it could well be very useful for automation, those ultimately this is a tease as I would guess I would have to pay for it)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't nearly all the functionality available via the webgui?

Comment: Can I just download this for free though, rather than pay for it or persuade the powers-that-be to spend their limited budget on this?

Comment: You should just have to enable the webgui on your SAP instance, and you'll be able to connect to it from a web browser.  I am not a basis admin though, so I don't have any idea what the technical details are.